# Assigning public ip address to ESXI

Tags: ip, static-ip, esxi

Ok, I am in a data center which has allocated 10 public IPs to me.

I need to allocate a public IP to a VM, do I need a seperate NIC per VM (which I imagine is totally not the case) or do I need to do something else.

I could not find a definite answer with an example.

Thanks!

ESXi 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only have a virtual NIC on the guest, and set up the virtual networks accordingly - you don't need a physical NIC for each addresses...

And of course, on the guests, you have to specify the IP addresses, just as you would with a physical machine.

Comment: So the virtual lan can get ips from the outside world? That was what stumped me.

Comment: If the networking is set up all right, then yes.

Comment: So, I don't set the IP in vSphre, I set it in the eth0 config right? The drop from the datacenter goes right to their switch. I have two drops, one for backup. How can I implement that into my setup?

Comment: Backup as in data backup, or as a redundant network connection?

Comment: As in redudancy.

Comment: [This page describes it](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004088)

Comment: Any chance we can talk on skype or something? I'd like to just pick your brain if you don't mind and make sure I have everything straight. My skype is natalicwolf - I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Thomas the thing is I'm absolutely not up to date and speed on this (I had to look up things even for these answers), it was during my student years I have dealt with ESXs (3.0 was the new hot thing back then), so I think the best would be to post your questions here, or even better: http://serverfault.com

Comment: Ok! I'll reask there to be on safe side. But the NIC overflow will be valuable.